# How to use coroutine as a pytest fixture?

Tags: python, tornado, pytest

Is it possible to write pytest fixtures as tornado coroutines? For example, I want to write a fixture for creating a db, like this:

```
from tornado import gen
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
@gen.coroutine
def get_db_connection():
    # set up
    db_name = yield create_db()
    connection = yield connect_to_db(db_name)

    yield connection

    # tear down
    yield drop_db(db_name)


@pytest.mark.gen_test
def test_something(get_db_connection):
    # some tests
```

Obviously, this fixture does not work as expected, as it is called as a function, not as coroutine. Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I came out with this solution:

```
from functools import partial
from tornado import gen
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def get_db_connection(request, io_loop): # io_loop is a fixture from pytest-tornado
    def fabric():
        @gen.coroutine
        def set_up(): 
            db_name = yield create_db()
            connection = yield connect_to_db(db_name)
            raise gen.Return(connection)
        @gen.coroutine
        def tear_down():
            yield drop_db(db_name)
        request.addfinalizer(partial(io_loop.run_sync, tear_down))
        connection = io_loop.run_sync(set_up)
        return connection

    return fabric


@pytest.mark.gen_test
def test_something(get_db_connection):
    connection = get_db_connection()  # note brackets
```

I'm sure, that it can be done cleaner using some pylint magic. 
I found [this slides](http://asvetlov.github.io/pytest-slides) very useful.

EDIT: I found out that above method has a limitation. You can't change scope of get_db_connection fixture, as it uses io_loop fixture with scope "function".